# How to set system brightness with help of any API in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a QSlider by which I can handle the brightness of the screen (not of the application) for actual screen.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qml-qtgraphicaleffects1-brightnesscontrast.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a platform-specific function, there is nothing in the Qt library.

On Linux you can do like:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9
```

"LVDS1" is the name of the display you want to change. Run xrandr and check the name of the display you have. The line will look something like "LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0".

You can also try this:

```
xbacklight -set 100
```

On windows you can use the Gamma Ramp API as [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/vc/change_screen_brightness.html). You can also use [WinI2C/DDC](http://www.nicomsoft.com/products/i2c/) which is a professional tool that allows you to control display devices in the Windows environment via the DDC/CI protocolthat. It is free for personal use and non-free for commercial use. They may even allow you to use it for free if you contact them and explain it's for a non-profit organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Shared library libddcutil from project [ddcutil](https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil) provides a C API for using DDC/CI.  The GUI program [ddcui](https://rockowitz/ddcui) is written in Qt and uses libddcutil. They are available on most Linux distributions, though the versions there can be dated.